# How do i open a javascript file, when someone clicks on a button?

Tags: javascript

I have a website and I have this javascript code im going to place in the header below

```
<!-- GATEWAY -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.al.com/al.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    al.check('f6687144358efd6746bc25f7c145f760'); 
</script>
```

Now I want to open that javascript when someone clicks on a button on my website. ( IMG HTML BUTTON )

Comment: What do you mean by "open that javascript"?

Comment: You mean you want to execute `al.check()` when the button is clicked?

Comment: i tried adding this to the img html code

Comment: onclick="al.check('f6687144358efd6746bc25f7c145f760');"

Answer (score 0):

What about putting it in the onclick?

```
<button onclick="javascript:al.check('f6687144358efd6746bc25f7c145f760');">
Click
</button>
```